# use if condition inside html tag using jinja tag

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, jinja2

i made a header for my site project and it has some sections...
i want to change the section color name on header using jinja but i can't
the template already rendered without error but section name doesn't change
and in pycharm this message shows up :Tag start is not closed

```
<ul class='menu'>
    <li {% if section == "dashboard" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
      <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">My dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li {% if section == "images" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
      <a href="#">Images</a>
    </li>
    <li {% if section == "people" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
      <a href="#">People</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show what `print((section, type(section)))` in your view shows. Perhaps `section` is not a string, or a string with a different value?

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul class='menu'>
    <li class="selected">
        {% if section == "dashboard" %}
          <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">My dashboard</a>
        {% elif section == "images" %}
          <a href="#">Images</a>
        {% elif section == "people" %}
          <a href="#">People</a>
        {% endif %}
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
{% if section == "dashboard" %}
<li class="selected">
{% else %}
<li>
{% endif %}
```